# Scaling and anchoring an image within an imageview

Tags: android, listview, layout, imageview

I am currently using a custom ArrayAdapter for a list. List items span the whole width of the screen so on some devices are very wide.

I overlay an `ImageView` on some of the list items which you can swipe to dismiss.
The xml for the `ImageView` is below:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:scaleType="matrix"
  android:src="@drawable/myImage" />
```

The view is placed correctly, but in order for the image to fit devices with really wide screens, or in landscape mode, the image has to be very wide.

The problem is, I want to scale the image to fit vertically (i.e. `fitY` which doesn't exist as a `scaleType`, then to anchor the image to the left of the view, and for everything that doesn't fit to be cropped.

I have tried all of the `scaleType` values, and none of them are quite right. As such, I felt I should probably use `matrix` and define my own translation for the image, so I tried this in `getView`:

```
//snipped out code before to initiate variables etc.
Drawable src = imageView.getDrawable();

//scale by the ratio of the heights.
int scaleFactor = imageView.getHeight() / src.getIntrinsicHeight();

Matrix imageMatrix = new Matrix();

//set the scale factor for the imageMatrix
imageMatrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

//set the translation to be 0,0 (top left);
imageMatrix.setTranslate(0,0);

//assign the image matrix to the imageview.
imageView.setImageMatrix(imageMatrix);
```

But this is not having any effect at all (even if I make the values really crazy). I presume I am setting the imageMatrix in the wrong place - is there an `onDraw()` event I can hook into for a custom `ArrayAdapter` subclass?

Or am I going about solving the problem in completely the wrong way?

Comment: Have you tried `@dimen/` for different size screen?

Comment: Can you explain how that would work?

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain in a few words but you can visit http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for more information. Let me know if you understand it. What Android version are you trying to design it for? If it's 3.0 and up, you can use it :)

Comment: Oh I see, you mean to use a different drawable depending on the size of the screen. This is an option, but it's still not ideal. Given there's not a limited set of screen widths (i.e. screens can really be *any* width) then you will still have to scale or stretch the image slightly.

Comment: You are correct but also remember if you have a "big" image, resizing it small does not always make the image blurry. You can look at a couple of my apps in Play Store which I designed using `@dimen/` and I tested in multiple screen size emulator and they work fine. (Here's one of them: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sikni8.colorfinders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I had to explicitly set `imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);` in code, then apply my `imageMatrix` to it. Using the xml attribute `scaleType="matrix"` didn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

The fitXY scaleType only work when you set the layout_width and layout_height to match_parent or fill_parent according to the API level that your are using for.
so you must use this code in your xml only:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
  android:src="@drawable/myImage" />
```

Comment: But I don't want to fit X and Y, just Y.

Comment: hey @EdHinchliffe,... i encountered the similar case. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023108/android-how-to-scaley-to-based-on-other-objects-position could you help me out as well?